# What's The Simplest Way of Coding Touch for Android Using onTouchListener?

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I've been collecting data on the internet and from what I've collected, I'm wondering if I could just create a class that implements onTouchListener and set that to my View instance.  I'm assuming I have to use "implements" and not "extends" because according to android APIs, onTouchListender is an interface.

For example, I'm thinking of doing something like this...

```
class public MyTchListener implements onTouchListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent, mevent){
        //write some code to handle touches.....

        return true;
    }



}
```

And then set it to my View instance...

```
MySurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new MyTchListener());
```

Would that actually work or did I leave something out?  Again, looking for the simplest code structure for achieving touch events.  I don't think I even need @Override because I'm dealing with an interface.

Now that I look at it, would I have to pass my view instance as the view argument in onTouch and do I need to actually define a MotionEvent?

As a former python programmer, this stuff is confusing for me.

Comment: I would probably recommend taking a look at some Java tutorials instead of diving straight into something specific, this question doesn't really concern Android at all. However what you've written is correct apart from the syntax error in the `onTouch` method and incorrect naming conventions.

Comment: As a side note, the `@Override` annotation is never necessary, but recommended. There is enough information out there to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

Could use the onTouchListener directly, its more simple:

```
MySurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //...
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it written like that before but would rather not define it at the same time as I set it.  Easier for me to keep code separated by not doing it like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
 import android.app.Activity;

 public class TouchListen implements OnTouchListener{
    Activity activity;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent mevent){
        // in here, you want to store touch data by calling mevent.getPointerCount()
        // the use a for loop to loop through the pointers
        // how you hand the data is up to you but what I dis was
        // process the state of the touches 1st by passing the data to a function
        // that checks to see if the touch happened over a UI element like a button
        // if so, then I set that button's pressed variable to true
        // I also store the action for that button in a variable (action down, up, 
           etc..)
        // I also store the id of the pointer and use those ids when the action is
        // equal to up.  I check every button's id and compare it to the incoming id
        // to find which button is at the up state.
        // after the touch event loop finishes, it calls a final function that process
        // the touches/button press based on the data that was pre-processed.
        // this allows me to give one GUI element priority over another one.

    }



    return true;  // must return true in order to process other events after touch
                  // like move, or up events.  Otherwise you get no reporting after
                  // initial touch.
}
```